# TouchesBegan only in specific UIView

Tags: uiview, location, touchesbegan

I have three `UIView` instances:

```
UIView *view1;
UIView *view2;
UIView *view3;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
 CGPoint startPoint =[touch locationInView:self.view];

}
```

But i want that the toch-action only go in view2. It doesnt work if i make: locationInView:view2

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
 CGPoint startPoint =[touch locationInView:view2];

}
```

What do I wrong? How can i check, which view is the view i actually can see on my iphone?

Answer (score 1):

set userInteractionEnabled to false in the view in which you don't want your touch to be handled.